# Preserve/Restore window layout

Tags: windows-7, multi-monitor

I'm running a Windows 7 x64 VM, which happens to be a p2v of my previous machine, and will still be used for apps that require Windows.  I have three monitors, and keep windows in various places across all three.

VMWare Workstation has a very annoying habit of unplugging/hotplugging the monitors on the VM.  It always resumes as single screen and then I have to cycle through the permutations to get all three screens back.  Unplugging the screens makes Windows move everything to fit on the remaining screen, even if the app is minimized.  It also messes up the relative positioning of the window on the logical desktop, even though it sets it right in the end: a program that's not running at the time (so not totally messed up) will have the remembered window positions offset from where they should be.

➼ **I'd like a program that restores windows to the positions I want.**
It specifically needs to work with things that are not a main app window, specifically the **floating palettes** of Photoshop et al.

If it requires manual "save" initiation, the remembered windows should be cumulative and not forget about apps that are not currently being displayed.  Best if it could automatically save when it detects a hot(un)plug event.

I've seen such functionality in the past, so I'm sure such a thing exists.  But that's really Plan C.  A better thing would be a way to tell Windows to keep the 3-monitor desktop no matter what got "unplugged".